# Why am I getting a strange "rubber band" reaction on an SKSpriteNode with physics?

Tags: swift, skspritenode

*****Updated info below**

Below is my code, and an image just to help understand what I am doing.

I create a greyBar below the bottom of the screen. I then move the greyBar up above the border. When that move is done, I change the collision mask so that the border will hold the greyBar when gravity brings it down.

Everything works as it should. Except when I lengthened the duration of the action from 1.0 to 10.0, when the move is done, the greyBar shoots up off the screen. It doesn't hit the borderBar and then bounce off. Wherever it is when the move action is done it  just "jumps up." Almost as if it had been on a rubber band. It shoots up off the screen and eventually comes back down.

What I don't understand is "why does it shoots up?"

This really is my only code for the moving of the greyBar. And at a lower duration the extreme jumping up action does not happen.

Does anyone know why this "jumping" action is happening?

```
greyBar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size, center: CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2))
greyBar.physicsBody!.isDynamic            = true
greyBar.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity    = true
greyBar.physicsBody!.restitution          = 0.3

let xConstraint = SKConstraint.positionX(SKRange(constantValue: (safeSceneRect.width/2) - (greyBar.size.width/2)))
greyBar.constraints = [xConstraint]

let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: (safeSceneRect.width/2) - (greyBar.size.width/2), y: (myBase.size.height)! + (myBorder.size.height)! + 5), duration: 1.0)
        
greyBar.run(moveAction, completion: 
                 { greyBar .physicsBody?.collisionBitMask   = 
                   bodyMasks.borderMask.rawValue|bodyMasks. greyBarMask.rawValue})
```

[image: screenshot]

*****additional info**
So I found the cause, and a work around, but not what I think is the final answer.

The border had its collision bit mark set to greyBar from the beginning. It's almost as if passing through the border, caused greyBar to have built up a bunch of kinetic energy. The more slowly it pass through the more built up energy the greyBar had.

My current work around is :

```
* All collision bit masks set to blank
* set greyBar to not be affected by gravity
* when done moving
       greyBar collision bit masks set to border mask
       border  collision bit masks set to greyBar
* set greyBar to be affected by gravity
```

This feels kludgy. Isn't there some command to release an object's built up energy?

Comment: If you remove `xConstraint` does the issue still happen?

Comment: @JohnL Yes it does. It appears the longer the duration of the move, the higher it jumps off screen. Is there some weird setting?

Comment: @JohnL Please see OP for updated info

Comment: I think I understand. When using the physics world, you would normally use applyForce, applyImpulse, set Velocity etc to move the physics bodies. As you are using SKActions, there can be unexpected collison behaviour in the physics world. Your greyBar would never pass through the border had you used the physics movements, but it did because of the skactions overwriting it. If you have to have the border as a physics body, and the grey bar as a physicsbody, you will have to change the collision bitmasks so one can pass through the other. Your kludgy work around could be an ok solution.